# How to send values from one popup to another popup in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I have an object in which the values of it is pushed into the object dynamically.

```
$scope.expndradiolabels=function(){
    $scope.order++;
    var objt={
            Name:"",
            type:"radiobtns",
            rbtn:[{
                      Name:"",
                      order:$scope.order
                  }]
                };

    $scope.radiolabels.push(objt);
};
```

In first pop up i just push the objt for every call of expndradiolabels.So now in the second pop up i need the push the objects  Name:"" ,order:$scope.order to rbtn in which those are the radio buttons and heading is the Name which is not inside the rtbn..How to push the values to the rtbn from the second pop up respectively to different headings in the first popup.

```
Expected Output:

Gender 
    radiobuttonsymbol Male
    radiobuttonsymbol Female
Language
    radiobuttonsymbol Telugu
    radiobuttonsymbol Hindi
etcc...
$scope.radiolabels=[];
    $scope.addradio=function(){
        ngDialog.open({
            template:"popupfiles/radioname.html",
            closeByDocument:false,
            closeByEscape:false,
            scope: $scope,
            showClose:false
        });
    };
    $scope.expndradiolabels=function(){
        $scope.order++;
        var objt={
                Name:"",
                type:"radiobtns",
                rbtn:[{
                          Name:"",
                          order:$scope.order
                      }]
                    };

        $scope.radiolabels.push(objt);
    };
    $scope.radioname="";
    $scope.saveradioname=function(){
        $scope.radioname=$("#radiofmname").val();
        ngDialog.closeAll();
        ngDialog.open({
            template:"popupfiles/radiopopup.html",
            closeByDocument:false,
            closeByEscape:false,
            scope: $scope,
            showClose:false,
            data:$scope.objt
        });
        angular.forEach($scope.radiolabels,function(rl){

        });
    };
    $scope.radiobuttons=[];
    var radios=[];
    angular.forEach($scope.form.fields,function(fi,index){
        if(fi.type=="radiobtns")
            {
                var objects={
                        Name:fi.Name,
                        type:"radiobtns",
                        order:index
                            };
                radios.push(objects);
            }
    });
    angular.forEach(radios,function(r){
        $scope.radiobuttons.push(r);
    });
    $scope.expndradio=function(){

        $scope.order++;
        var objt={
                type:"radiobtns",
                order:$scope.order,
                rbtns:[]
                    };
        $scope.radiobuttons.push(objt);


    };
    $scope.deleteradiobtn=function(index){

        $scope.deletedItems.push($scope.radiobuttons[index]);
        $scope.radiobuttons.splice(index, 1);
    };
    $scope.saveradiobutton=function(){
        //console.log(angular.toJson(ngDialogData.rbts));
        angular.forEach($scope.radiobuttons,function(ra){
            if($scope.form.fields[ra.order]){
                $scope.form.fields[ra.order].rbtns[ra.order].Name=ra.Name;
            }
            else{
                $scope.form.fields.push({Label:$scope.radioname,type:"radiobtns",rbts:[{Name:ra.Name,order:ra.order}]});
            }
        });
        angular.forEach($scope.deletedItems,function(items){

            $scope.form.fields.splice(items.order, 1);
            console.log(angular.toJson($scope.form.fields));
        }); 
        $scope.deletedItems = [];
        console.log(angular.toJson($scope.form.fields));
        ngDialog.closeAll();
};

    $scope.cancelradiobutton=function(){
        ngDialog.closeAll();
    };
```

Comment: are both popups binded to the same controller?

Comment: a.yes.Both are in the same constroller.

Comment: Once analyse the code.I have edited the question

Comment: you can use a scope variable to exchange data between the 2 popups

Comment: Can u guess what to do in that above code to aquire that